# How to Capture Screen using Python with better frame rate

Tags: python, opencv

So i have this code, which records my screen and saves it as output.avi
but it only captures 10-15 frames per second. How do i make it capture around 50-60 frames at least. if i am not wrong cv2 is cpu based or something. how do i use gpu to do this task ?

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
video = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi",fourcc,8,(1920,1080))

while(True):
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    image = np.array(image)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    video.write(frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.imshow("Hello",frame)
    if(key==27):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you're on mac, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185388/2286337). You can define a [`bbox`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.PIL.ImageGrab.grab) and see if it increases speed.

Comment: i know about bbox. but i want 50-60 fps without adjusting my resolution. even if i adjust it. it won't be big difference anyways. i don't want to compromise.

Comment: Have you tried using `ffmpeg` or **QuickTime**? How long do you want to record for?

Comment: yea i can get away with ffmpeg for screen recording, for that i will have to use it as sub process in python i guess. but what i want to do is capture the frames and send it through socket to other host like teamviewer does and plot it on remote computer.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend you to use [MSS](https://pypi.org/project/mss/) instead of cv2 to capture the screen. cv2 is useful to handle image data, but no good at capturing. On the other hand, mss runs much faster than any other screen capture APIs. I used mss to apply object detection([YOLOv2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf), [darkflow](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow)), and it run at over 40 frames per second. If it is used without any object detection, it should run at more fps. Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import time

color = (0, 255, 0) # bounding box color.

# This defines the area on the screen.
mon = {'top' : 10, 'left' : 10, 'width' : 1000, 'height' : 800}
sct = mss()
previous_time = 0
while True :
    sct.get_pixels(mon)
    frame = Image.frombytes( 'RGB', (sct.width, sct.height), sct.image )
    frame = np.array(frame)
    # image = image[ ::2, ::2, : ] # can be used to downgrade the input
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow ('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey ( 1 ) & 0xff == ord( 'q' ) :
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    txt1 = 'fps: %.1f' % ( 1./( time.time() - previous_time ))
    previous_time = time.time()
    print txt1
```