# How can I use the screen as a video input to darkflow

Tags: python-imaging-library, screen-capture, darkflow

I've trained darkflow on my data set and have good result! I can feed it a pre recorded image or video and it draws the bounding boxes around the right things, win!

Now I'd like to run it live as has been done with camera feeds, except I'd like my feed to be from the screen, not the camera. I have a specific window, which is launched from a specific process, or I can just take a section of the screen (from coords) either is fine for my application.

Currently I use PILs image grab and then feed the images into darkflow, but this feels quite slow (maybe a few frames per second) nothing like the 30 ish fps you can get with video files!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageGrab.grab() method is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140586/imagegrab-grab-method-is-too-slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get more than 25 fps with [Python MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss) on my slow laptop under Ubuntu.

Here is an example:

```
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import time

def capture_screenshot():
    with mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        # Convert to PIL/Pillow Image
        return Image.frombytes('RGB', sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')

N = 100
t = time.time()
for _ in range(N):
    capture_screenshot()
print ("Frame rate = %.2f fps" % (N/(time.time()-t)))
```

Output:

```
Frame rate = 27.55 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

I got over 40 fps with this script (on i5-7500 3.4GHz, GTX 1060, 48GB RAM). 
There are a lot of APIs used to capture the screen. Among them, mss runs much faster and is not difficult to use. Here is an implementation of mss with darkflow([YOLOv2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf)), in which 'mon' defines the area you want apply prediction on the screen.

*options* is passed to the darkflow, that specifies which config file and checkpoint we want to use, threshold for detection, and how much this process occupies the GPU. Before we run this script, we have to have at least one trained model (or Tensorflow checkpoint). Here, *load* is the checkpoint number.

If you think that the network detects too many bounding boxes, I recommend you to lower the *threshold*.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import time

options = {
    'model' : 'cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg' ,
    'load' : 5500,
    'threshold' : 0.1,
    'gpu' : 0.7 }
tfnet = TFNet( options )
color = (0, 255, 0) # bounding box color.

# This defines the area on the screen.
mon = {'top' : 10, 'left' : 10, 'width' : 1000, 'height' : 800}
sct = mss()
previous_time = 0
while True :
    sct.get_pixels(mon)
    frame = Image.frombytes( 'RGB', (sct.width, sct.height), sct.image )
    frame = np.array(frame)
    # image = image[ ::2, ::2, : ] # can be used to downgrade the input
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = tfnet.return_predict( frame )
    for result in results :
        tl = ( result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y'] )
        br = ( result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y'] )
        label = result['label']
        confidence = result['confidence']
        text = '{} : {:.0f}%'.format( label, confidence * 100 )
        frame = cv2.rectangle( frame, tl, br, color, 5 )
        frame = cv2.putText( frame, text, tl, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2 )
    cv2.imshow ( 'frame', frame )
    if cv2.waitKey ( 1 ) & 0xff == ord( 'q' ) :
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    txt1 = 'fps: %.1f' % ( 1./( time.time() - previous_time ))
    previous_time = time.time()
    print txt1
```

Comment: What machine do you run this on? This is something I worked on a looong time ago, but I might pick it back up again!

Comment: @user6916458 i5-7500(3.4GHz), GTX 1060, 48GB RAM

Comment: @user6916458 
The fps heavily depends on what API you use to capture the screen. I tried some APIs, but mss was surprisingly fast among them.