# ImageGrab.grab() method is too slow but alternatives don't return the rgb colour

Tags: python, performance, python-imaging-library, rgb

I need to be able to return the RGB of a certain pixel as fast as I can but the scrip below is too slow (doesn't return the RBG fast enough per second.)

```
while True:
    x = 960
    y = 540
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[x,y]
    if rgb == (xxx,xxx,xxx):
        mouse.click('left')
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        print(rgb)
```

There is a post addressing this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140586/imagegrab-grab-method-is-too-slow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but none of the solutions clearly show how to return the RGB of the pixel/area, only screenshot it.

I have tried using the script

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Get a screenshot of the center pixel of the first monitor
    sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
    monitor = {"top": 540, "left": 960, "width": 1, "height": 1}
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
    output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)
```

But haven't quite figured out to return the RGB of the chosen pixel.

Maybe it would work if I used the second script then translated the output into RGB but I'm not quite sure how I'd go about doing this.

Comment: ImageGrab grabs the entire screen.  If you want to grab one pixel, you may need to use operating-system specific APIs.  Are you on Windows?

Comment: You would need to dig deep into the Windows API to do it any faster than a screen grab.  Not sure if Python is the best language for that.

Comment: IF they are on Windows, it's actually fairly easy with the PyWIn32 module that almost everyone uses.  It's just GetDC and GetPixel.  It's still not going to be super-quick; the graphics card makers optimize going TO the screen, not coming FROM the screen.

Comment: reply@TimRoberts yes I am on windows, what sort of API's and programming languages would work as I have little knowledge but am definitely willing to do some research and figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion of using pywin32, I am definitely going to give that a go and run some tests to see which one's quickest.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I have 2 monitors, so its very slow :/
You can try:

```
PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, 500, 300).load()[0,0]
```

(I don't know what "500,300" really means)
But personally, I don't see a huge difference

Comment: `500, 300` is the bottom right coordinate of the area you're cropping, while `x, y` is the top left coordinate

Comment: When using this I get the response
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'load'`

Answer (score 0):

About the performance: at least on Linux (X11), `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` by default uses `gnome-screenshot`, as [stated in the official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.grab). To disable this and enable direct X11 calls (if available), set `xdisplay=""`. In my system, taking a full 1920x1200 screenshot, this setting alone made an improvement from ~**3.30 FPS** / 303.3ms per call to a whooping **80.27 FPS** / 12.45ms!

As for getting the `(r, g, b)` value of a pixel, just use... [`getpixel()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel):

```py
def find_color(x, y, rgb_ref):
    while True:
        rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(xdisplay="").getpixel((x, y))
        if rgb == rgb_ref:
            mouse.click('left')
        else:
            print(rgb)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Also notice I moved the `time.sleep()` call to *after* the `if` block. Unless you're doing a benchmark, never use a fully busy loop and always insert the pause on every cycle of the `while True` loop.

Comment: This is very helpful but I am on windows so i get the response `OSError: Pillow was built without XCB support`. The only alternative to using xdisplay that i have found is bbox but using this i cannot seen to get the output of a single pixel.

Comment: Does it work fine on Windows if you remove the `xdisplay=""` argument? If so, at least the question on _**how**_ to get the RGB tuple is answered. As for performance, you could refactor this so it takes a single screenshot for multiple `.getpixel((x, y))` calls.