# How to take low-resolution screenshots in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I am working on a simple program that will draw your computer screen as ASCII art, live, and am having some performance issues. The problem is that my computer's screen is very high resolution, so it takes a while for the screenshot to be created. Currently I take a full-res screenshot, then lower the resolution so that it can fit into ASCII art. Rather than lowering the resolution afterwards, is it possible to take a screenshot in a lowered resolution? I am currently using the PIL library, using ImageGrab.grab() to take the screenshot.

I am using OSX.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: **Exactly** how are you reducing the size currently? What OS are you using? Have you considered changing your display properties so your resolution is lower?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using OSX, and I have tried changing the resolution yes, but it doesn’t let you lower it enough. Ideally I want to lower it so that the width is 800px

Comment: This answer maybe help [go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185388/13636459)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of [`PIL.ImageGrab.grab()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html):

> `bbox` – What **region** to copy. Default is the entire screen. Note that on Windows OS, the top-left point may be negative if all_screens=True is used.

> `xdisplay` – X11 Display address. Pass `None` to grab the default system screen. Pass `""` to grab the default X11 screen on Windows or macOS.

Thus for a reduced dimension of the screenshot, you can

- either **reduce the bounding-box** to take the screenshot from a smaller region of the entire screen only (parameter `bbox`)
- or try to create a *virtual display* on your OS which has a lower resolution. Then take the screenshot from that **smaller screen** (parameter `xdisplay`)

See also:

1. Ask Ubuntu: [Taking screenshot of higher resolution than actual display resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059070/taking-screenshot-of-higher-resolution-than-actual-display-resolution)
2. X11 docs: [`XRANDR`](https://x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) man page for creating a virtual screen with lower resolution in X11